# Minimally invasive frozen HTML table header row

Tags: html, css

There are many different ways to freeze a header row of an HTML table, but I need something **minimally invasive**. I'm working in a large and complex system in which the table HTML is generated through many layers of back-end coding and it will be non-trivial and risky to change the table structure (lots of complex JavaScript and CSS depends on the HTML structure remaining as-is and I don't want to break anything).

So I'm looking for a way to freeze my HTML header rows (2 rows need to be frozen, not just 1) by changing/adding only CSS and/or adding attributes to the table or rows in the table. Here's an accurate example of my table:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <th id="col0">Option ID</th>
            <th id="col1">Description</th>
            <th id="col2" title="Sort on Description">Description</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <td title="Filter on Option ID (Text)">
                <input type="text" id="f0">
            </td>
            <td title="Filter on Description (Text)>
                <input type="text" id="f1">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="radio" name="chk0" id="c_01Q0"></td>
            <td>0093005</td>
            <td>Local pickup & delivery.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>...etc...</tr>
        <tr>...etc...</tr>
        <tr>...etc...</tr>
        <tr>...etc...</tr>
        <tr>...etc...</tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see it's nothing exotic. But as I've searched for solutions I have found a lot of [examples like this](https://jsfiddle.net/dPixie/byB9d/3/), which require more structural changes to the HTML than I dare make (I'm mainly just worried about having to surround the table by `section` and `div` elements -- and it seems like a lot of CSS just to freeze a header row). The 1st two rows both need to be frozen so that when I scroll down, they remain nicely in-place. The first data row (non-frozen) is the row containing *0093005*.

A few objectives/desires:

1. Brevity is more important than elegance. I'm fine with a hack, in this case.
2. Don't change the HTML structure if at all possible, though adding attributes to existing elements can be done.
3. Pure CSS additions/changes without touching the HTML would be ideal, but I suspect the HTML will need to be decorated to some extent, and that is ok.
4. Use of JS or jQuery is a last resort only, to be avoided if possible.

Comment: You realise your html is invalid? Duplicate `id` values are not permitted.

Comment: I haven't finished reading though this, but the fact that you have 2 HTML elements with the same ID (`col0`) is already throwing red flags for me.

Comment: The duplicate IDs occurred in my example as I pieced it together but it doesn't happen in the real system. Sorry for the confusion. I have fixed my code sample.

Answer (score 2):

### Sticky `<table>` Header (CSS Only)

If the `<table>` HTML in the question was semantically correct, it would have a `<thead>` set before the `<tbody>`. With a single `<tr>` in `<thead>` CSS would be:

1. ```
   table { position: relative;...}
   ```
2. ```
   thead th, td { position: sticky; top: 0;...}
   ```

See this [article](https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-and-table-headers/) for details

Unfortunately, either the `<table>` was copied badly or it was badly designed. The example below uses `position: sticky` to make the first two `<tr>` of the malformed `<table>` sticky. BTW, `#col2` was an extra `<th>` so it was removed. My sympathies go with you, I worked front-end and all of the tables were beyond my control until it reached me as a ugly pile of trash.

```css
/*
<table> must be a positioned tag so that any positioned
tags within can reference their position to the <table>
border. 
*/

table {
  position: relative;
}


/*
If you haven't already assigned backgrounds, I suggest you 
do so even if it's just white.
*/

th,
td {
  background: cornsilk;
}


/*
This targets all <th> of the first <tr> to stick.
top is 0 offset in relation to the top of <table>
*/

tr:first-child th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}


/* 
This targets all <th> and <td> in the 2nd <tr> 
to stick. top has to be offset to the height of the
first <tr>
*/

tr:nth-child(2) th,
tr:nth-child(2) td {
  position: sticky;
  top: 3ex/* This is the equal to 3 "x"s stacked on top of 
  each other which is roughly the height of the first row */
  ;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th id="col0">Option ID</th>
      <th id="col1">Description</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <td title="Filter on Option ID (Text)">
        <input type="text" id="f0">
      </td>
      <td title="Filter on Description (Text)">
        <input type="text" id="f1">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="radio" name="chk0" id="c_01Q0"></td>
      <td>0093005</td>
      <td>Local pickup & delivery.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: LOL "Unfortunately, either the <table> was copied badly or it was badly designed" I suspect the latter is the case.  Been there with an inherited large fragile 20 year old code base myself.  Pretty nice and small for the objective methinks here!